# Quartz properties does not work currently with Autofac.Extras.Quartz

Tags: asp.net, autofac, scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I'm using `Autofac.Extras.Quartz` in asp.net mvc and i setup `quartz`(include properties for using job store feature) like this:

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection();
            properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "myDS";
            properties["quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString"] = "my connection string";
            properties["quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider"] = "SqlServer";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
            properties["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json";

            builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule
            {
                JobScopeConfigurator = (builder, jobScopeTag) => {
                    builder.Register(orm => new ORM(HttpContext.Current, "my connection string")).As<IORM>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(jobScopeTag);
                },ConfigurationProvider = p => properties
            });
            builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacJobsModule(typeof(DefaultJob).Assembly));
```

but none of these properties work(i am not receiving any exceptions for incorrect properties, but it seems that i have not passed any properties at all).
for example i sat job store feature with properties and its not working with db at all but when i setup all these properties in a simple way without `Autofac.Extras.Quartz` and `Autofac` libraries and it works fine, simple code that is working :

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection();
            properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "myDS";
            properties["quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString"] = "my connection string";
            properties["quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider"] = "SqlServer";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
            properties["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json";

            StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            IScheduler scheduler = factory.GetScheduler().Result;


            scheduler.Start().Wait();
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<DefaultJob>().Build();
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?", x => x.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Iran Standard Time")))
                .Build();
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job,trigger).Wait();
```

Make all properties work and throw exceptions for incorrect properties.

Comment: I think you are registering the `QuartzAutofacFactoryModule` module twice, first with the configuration but the second time would overwrite those registrations without configuration
`builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule {...});
builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());`